# PHP CURL requests gets force redirected to "www", direct request doesnt

Tags: php, redirect, curl, web

For some reason, when I am making a CURL call to a test URL on my server, the request gets forcefully kicked off to a URL with "www". VirtualHost does not have any settings to modify the URL, htaccess does not seem to either. When making a direct request to 'http://sub.domain.com/test.html' in the browser, I get actual page contents.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://sub.domain.com/test.html');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

return varDumpToString($info);
```

This returns:

```
array(22) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(37) "http://sub.domain.com/test.html"
    ["content_type"]=>
    string(29) "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
    ["http_code"]=>
    int(301)
    ["header_size"]=>
    int(311)
    ["request_size"]=>
    int(68)
    ["filetime"]=>
    int(-1)
    ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
    int(0)
    ["redirect_count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["total_time"]=>
    float(0.003001)
    ["namelookup_time"]=>
    float(0.000552)
    ["connect_time"]=>
    float(0.002219)
    ["pretransfer_time"]=>
    float(0.002226)
    ["size_upload"]=>
    float(0)
    ["size_download"]=>
    float(331)
    ["speed_download"]=>
    float(110296)
    ["speed_upload"]=>
    float(0)
    ["download_content_length"]=>
    float(331)
    ["upload_content_length"]=>
    float(0)
    ["starttransfer_time"]=>
    float(0.002958)
    ["redirect_time"]=>
    float(0)
    ["certinfo"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["redirect_url"]=>
    string(41) "http://www.sub.domain.com/test.html"
}
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Http code 301 means a permanent redirection, and the client side will post a new request follow the redirection_url. You should check the redirection settings in the server side.

Comment: As stated above, no redirects are setup to happen.

Comment: Tried running "curl -v sub.domain.com" from ssh to get more info. It appears that "sub.domain.com" resolves to a IPv6 of "domain.com", which has redirects. Now, I am not sure why the subdomain is redirecting to the main domain even though A Host records for sub.domain.com are explicitly set.

Comment: There is a problem, there must be some reason. Do not "think" or "guess" everything is right. The result shows a redirection there must be somewhere redirect the request. I suggest to check the server config and php code carefully. Is there a host name validation? Follow the data flow to check carefully and minimize the area where the problem may happens.